# Converting Ruby class object to JSON and back, when containing other nested class objects (not using Rails or Active Support)

Tags: json, ruby

I've become confused while writing custom `to_json` and `from_json` methods for a class.  I have actually found a solution, but don't understand why it works, nor why my initial attempt does not work.

I have a People class that initializes by taking an instance of a Person class as a paramater.
The to_json/from_json methods in Person have been copied in from a generic 
external module, and therefore a bit wordy...but worked when I tested it on an individual instance of a Person object.

The problem comes when re-creating the People object from JSON.  For the `@person` instance variable, I'm expecting:

```
#<Person:0x00000001a0b440 @name="Jon", @age=22, @gender="male">
```

Instead, I'm getting @person as an array (and thus, only the keys):

```
#<People:0x00000001b5c038 @person=["@name", "@age", "@gender"]>
```

Full code is as follows:

```
require "json"

class Person

  attr_accessor :name, :age, :gender

  def initialize(name, age, gender)
    @name = name
    @age = age
    @gender = gender
  end

  def to_json
    obj = {}
    instance_variables.map do |var|
      obj[var] = instance_variable_get(var)
    end
    JSON.dump(obj)
  end

  def from_json(string)
    obj = JSON.parse(string)
    obj.keys.each do |key|
      instance_variable_set(key, obj[key])
    end
  end

end

class People

  attr_accessor :person

  def initialize(person)
    @person = person
  end

  def to_json
    obj = {}
    obj[:person] = @person.to_json
    JSON.dump(obj)
  end

  def from_json(string)
    obj = JSON.parse(string, {:symbolize_names => true})
    person = Person.new("", 0, "")
    @person = person.from_json(obj[:person])
  end

  def <<(person)
    @persons << person
  end

end
```

After re-writing the `to_json` and `from_json` methods as below, the problem seems to have been solved...and now correctly re-assembles @person  as expected.

```
def to_json
  obj = {}
  obj[:persons] = [@person.to_json]
  JSON.dump(obj)
end

def from_json(string)
  obj = JSON.parse(string, {:symbolize_names => true})
  persons = []
  obj[:persons].each do |person_string|
    person = Person.new("", 0, "")
    person.from_json(person_string)
    persons << person
  end
  @person = persons[0]
end
```

I'm happy to have found a solution, but I can't understand why encasing the single Person object in an array would solve the situation.

I'm sure there are many other ways to solve this particular situation (and other methods completely... eg: other gems, or using Rails Active Support...), but I'm simply trying to get a more solid understanding why my initial idea doesn't work...to help later on when things get more complicated.

Thank you for any help you can offer...

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution works. You simply forgot to return from  your method. See below:

```
def from_json(string)
obj = JSON.parse(string, {:symbolize_names => true})
person = Person.new("", 0, "")
@person = person.from_json(obj[:person])
obj  #RETURN THE OBJECT HERE
end
```

In the second solution you are still missing the return value however  Ruby  implicitly returns the last evaluated expression from the method which by chance happens to be correct. This is the same reason why  your first solution didn't work.

Comment: yilmazgunalp: Thank you for help.  However, adding the line to return the 'obj' didn't  seem to solve my situation.  Perhaps I misunderstood your suggestion...My understanding of the from_json idea, is that we parse the json string (here: "obj"),  and assign each saved portion (eg: person object) to the instance variables of the newly created People object.  So, in your suggesting that I return the json string object (obj), I'm not sure to where I should returning it.  As well, in both versions, it seems that I'm already returning @person implicitly...so still not sure why different results.